# Macro clang: shifting a negative signed value is undefined

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Есть макрос, он вызывается из других макросов которые формируют значения для него. Все вроде ничего, но `clang` ругается, есть желание убрать :)

```
warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
```

Ругань естественно происходит при сборки с ключами: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`
При этом при сборке `gcc` с теми же ключами предупреждений нет, молчит.

Я постарался собрать часть значений на которых у `clang` нервная реакция и изобразил простенький пример:

**t-macro.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define __NELE(A) (sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]))
#define R(a,b) ((uint32_t)(((a == 0x80) ? (0x40 - b) : -a) << 23))

const uint32_t bittab[] = {
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0x1),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0x2),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0x3),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0x4),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0x5),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0x6),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0x7),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0x8),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0x9),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0xa),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0xb),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0xc),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0xd),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0xe),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | 0xf),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | (0x1 + 16)),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) | (0x2 + 16)),
    (R(0x80,0xc0) >> 6),
    R(0xa0,0xc0)
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint32_t i;
    (void) argc; (void) argv;

    for (i = 0; i < __NELE(bittab); i++)
        printf("\t%u)\t[%u]\t-> [0x%X]\n", i, bittab[i], bittab[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Собирается: `cc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic t-macro.c`

Какие есть мысли **где** поправить макрос, понятно что нужно проверять значение, но глаз замылился, не пойму где.
Заранее спасибо за участие в решении проблемы.

P.S. `clang version 5.0.0`

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете в виду под "подправить". Подавить предупреждение, не меняя вычислений? Или поменять вычисления, чтобы избежать сдвига отрицательных? У вас сейчас вообще *всегда* сдвигается отрицательное значение. `0x40 - 0xc0` - отрицательное, `-0x80` - тоже отрицательное.

Comment: Поправить предупреждения, результат вроде правильный, более полный выхлоп работы [этого макроса](https://travis-ci.com/ClnViewer/LibWchar2/jobs/133275852)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, ваш код вообще не компилируется под GCC с pedantic, ибо переполнение при вычислении константных выражений - запрещено языком ("error: initializer element is not a constant expression").

Во-вторых, учитывая природу ваших вычислений, вам надо бы их производить в домене *беззнакового* типа. Например, сделайте все константы беззнаковыми при помощи суффикса `u`. В принципе, достаточно

```
#define R(a,b) ((uint32_t)(((a == 0x80) ? (0x40u - b) : -a) << 23))
```

но лучше все аккуратно насильно загнать в беззнаковый домен.

Comment: Компилируется gcc, у меня по крайней мере. Спасибо, отличное решение!

Comment: А если перещитывать в беззнаковый домен, то по какому алгоритму любопытно? Это Unicode значения, мне не очевидно как корректно перещитать все возможные варианты.

Comment: @NewView: Оно "компилируется" в GCC-шном суржике, а достаточно включить настоящий С, как компилироваться перестает.

Comment: Аа, ну это может быть :) я жёсткие эксперименты на соответствие стандартам не проводил, не до этого :) а с каким флагом std перестаёт компилиться кстати?

Comment: Не, в лоб не заработало: `error: signed and unsigned type in conditional expression` с флагом `u` (`-Werror=sign-compare`)

Comment: Вот так собралось вроде `R(a,b) R_(__WEV(a,U),__WEV(b,U))` где `__WEV(a,b)` конкататор, осталось проверить результат :)

Comment: Да, [результат](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80b86bf562496043) вроде совпадает, большое спасибо @Ant